# Which operator must be disabled to prevent passing by value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

Of all the moove, copy, copy assign... operators

Which must be deleted to avoid an object from being passed by value? For example.

```cpp
class MyClass { int val; };
```

As is the following can be declared:

```cpp
void Fun(MyClass param) {}
```

I would like the compiler to complaint in this case, but be happy when passing by reference

i.e these 2 are fine:

```cpp
void Fun(MyClass& param) {}
void Fun(const MyClass& param) {}
```

Comment: passing by value accepts lvalues and rvalues so disallowing those means you would need to make you class non-copyable and non-moveable.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. You cannot "prevent" it. Even if the copy constructor is deleted a class instance can always constructed as a temporary, as long as there is a way to construct an instance, in any way.

Comment: Why do you want the compiler to complain about `void Fun(MyClass param) {}`? Even with all copy and move operations disabled, if there is e.g. a usable constructor for `MyClass` it can still be called as `Fun(MyClass(/*args*/))` or `Fun({/*args*/})`.

Comment: There are a few ways of disabling pass by value for a class, but they don't involve changing an operator. Simple approaches include making copy constructor and move constructor `private` (inaccessible to code trying to pass an object by value) or - since C++11 - `delete`ing those constructors.   Marking a destructor `private` achieves a similar thing (since it's not possible to construct a temporary object if its destructor is inaccessible).    This doesn't prevent *declaring* a function that accepts an argument by value, but does limit ability to *call* it.

Comment: *"I would like the compiler to complaint in this case"* -- why? What harm does this do? (Once you know why this is harmful, there is probably a more targeted approach to prevent that harm.)